# Ember rails Assertion Failed: template must be a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to set up a rails project with ember and i followed the steps on the ember-rails github page.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '~> 1.9.0'
```

I have now created a basic structure with a router and some hbs templates.
When I check Ember.TEMPLATES the templates are there but when ember wants to render them I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: template must be a function. 
Did you mean to call Ember.Handlebars.compile("...") or specify templateName instead?
```

I've looked around and tried multiple possible solutions to no avail. Does anyone know how to get the templates to compile properly with ember-rails?